# sed is not replacing all occurences when using cat

Tags: sed

when I apply the following to the tail of a file:

```
tail test9 | sed -e '/},/N;s/,\n*\]/]/g' >wtf
```

I get the correct result:

```
{"_id":{"},oid":"58dc04a9fbca629d612f1905"},"memberID":"114526","gender":"M","a    ge":"33","ethnicOriginCountryName":"Egypt","sect":"SU"},
{"_id":{"},oid":"58dc04a9fbca629d612f190d"},"memberID":"114534","gender":"M","age":"24","ethnicOriginCountryName":"United Kingdom","sect":"SU"}]
```

however when using cat

```
cat test9 | sed -e '/},/N;s/,\n*\]/]/g' >wtf
```

I do not get the correct result:

```
{"_id":{"},oid":"58dc04a9fbca629d612f1905"},"memberID":"114526","gender":"M","age":"33","ethnicOriginCountryName":"Egypt","sect":"SU"},
{"_id":{"},oid":"58dc04a9fbca629d612f190d"},"memberID":"114534","gender":"M","age":"24","ethnicOriginCountryName":"United Kingdom","sect":"SU"},
]
```

Comment: `sed` is line oriented stream editor. It will never detect `\n` as you claimed it did in scenario 1.

Comment: Can the second quote be considered the sample input (since no replace occurred on it)? And is the first quote the desired output? Can you describe in prose what you want to achieve? In the first quote there seems to be accidental white space inside the word "age", which is not caused by the sed line you provided. Are line ending differences (windows "\r\n" or nix "\n") in the scope of the question? Are we looking at the two last lines of the input file? The first two lines? The only two lines? Did you try to use the "l" command to get a better idea on special characters getting in the way?

Comment: @alvits Your reputation indicates that your statement has more substance than I can see at first glance. Could you elaborate? I tried  sed "N;s/\n/##/", then enter a<return>, b<return>. The result is a##b. The "N" command adds a newline to pattern space and the following input line. An attempt to replace "\n" with "##" succeeds. Note that OP has an "N" in his sed line. So I believe sed will find the "\n" in scenario 1.

Comment: @alvits I did. Created a textfile "ab.txt" with a<LF>b<LF><LF> (hope you know what I mean). Output is "a##b" for sed "N;s/\n/##/" ab.txt. Using GNU sed version 4.2.1 on a windows command prompt.

Comment: @Yunnosch - thanks for testing it. Now it's clear why it fails and why it succeeded with `tail`. `N` will append the next line to the pattern space. When a line is appended to the pattern space, the regex no longer apply to that line. This `sed 'N;s\n/|/' file` will show that the lines are appended every other lines so the output will be `lines 1|2`, `lines 3|4`, etc.

Comment: @alvits Not sure I can follow that in detail. The effect on line pairs is clear to me, but I do not see how tail helps. But sounds like you can give a helpful answer. Maybe with a bit more room and markdown to elaborate it is easier to explain than in a comment. And I like questions which have a solution to also have an official answer.

Comment: `tail` does not display the whole file. The line in question is in even numbered line when `cat`ted, while in `tail` it could be in odd numbered line. I am assuming the test input file is just the last 3 lines of the real file.

Comment: @Yunnosch - the input is a mangled json, probably caused by some pre-processing. `sed` is not the right tool for json. The OP should be using `jq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `N` command in `sed` has its limitations. It works if the input is pair of lines. In your case the input is not just pair of lines, but rather a paragraph ended by `]`.

The solution is to keep reading the whole paragraph, then replacing `\n,]` with `,]`, then finally printing the paragraph.

```
sed -e '1h;1!H;/]/!d' -e 'x;s/,\n]/]/;s/]\n//' test9
```

Here's what each of those `sed` commands do:

`1h` - if it is line 1, replace hold space with the contents of pattern space.

`1!H` - except line 1, append a newline followed by the contents of pattern space to the hold space.

`/]/!d` - delete pattern space except when it contains pattern `/]/`.

`x` - swap the contents of the pattern and hold spaces.

`s/,\n]/]/` - replace `,\n]` with `,]`.

`s/]\n//` - remove the pattern `]\n` which were inadvertenly pre-pended.

One word of advise, `sed` is not the right tool when working on `json` objects. Use `jq`. Your input seems to be a broken (mangled) json therefore `jq` will no longer work on it.

Thanks to [@Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7733418/yunnosch) for some help.

Comment: @yunnosch - I posted a solution in case you are curious.